# slick carousel individual slide duration

Tags: jquery, carousel, slick.js

Looking for a way to use slick carousel and be able to change the amount of time the slide is displayed on an individual slide basis.

In case I'm not explaining it well, assume I have 5 slides.  I want to be able to define the display of slide one for 5s, slide 2 for 10s, slide 3 for 7s, etc...

ref: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing but since I did not find any answer to setting an individual slide duration I built it with a recursive function that calls the 'slickNext' after timeout. The duration for each slide is stored in a data-attribute and then I save all durations in a list.

```
var durationList = $('.slider__item').map(function(index, item) {
    return item.getAttribute('data-time');
});

var slideIndex = 0;
var changeSlide = function(timing) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (timing !== 0) slider.slick('slickNext');
        if (slideIndex >= durationList.length) slideIndex = 0; //Start from beginning?
        changeSlide(durationList[slideIndex++]); //Calls itself with duration for next slide
    }, timing);
}

changeSlide(0);
```

See full example: http://codepen.io/calsal/pen/rLwydX

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: Simple and clever solution! Thank you, @Casal.

Comment: There is small issue with this solution. When use arrows and manual switching current index position breaks. I would offer to get the current index with slick method slider.slick('slickCurrentSlide'). Also no need to map all slides then and just change next slide with: changeSlide(slider.find('.slick-slide')[slider.slick('slickCurrentSlide')].getAttribute('data-time'));

Comment: I like the effort of improvement but that solution would be more inefficient. `slider.find()` would go through the DOM tree and search for correct slide every time the slide is changed and that's a big difference from using `map()` once.

Answer (score 2):

The above accepted question only works if your Slickslider fades to the next slide. If you use the default settings of Slick, the slider creates cloned slides, which means your data-attribute will be placed on a different slide, and the timing will be off for once in a while.

The code profided below will fix this problem.

```
 /* Init slider */
if ($slider.length > 0) {
        $slider.slick({
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            dots: true,
            arrows: false,
            speed: 1000

        });
        var activeSlides,
            currActiveSlide,
            firstSlide =  $slider.find("[data-slick-index='0']");

        $slider.on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
            activeSlides = slick.$slides;
            $.each(activeSlides, function(k, v){
                if ($(v).hasClass('slick-active')){
                    if ($(v).next().length){
                        currActiveSlide = $(v).next();
                    } else {
                        currActiveSlide = firstSlide;
                    }
                    return;
                }
            });
        });

        $slider.on('afterChange', function(event, slick){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $slider.slick('slickNext');
            }, currActiveSlide.data('time')-1000); 
        });

        // on init
        setTimeout(function(){
            $slider.slick('slickNext');
        },firstSlide.data('time'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.You can use bootstrap carousel and set the "data-interval" attribute based on your requirement.

Refer:
[How to change the interval time on bootstrap carousel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147394/how-to-change-the-interval-time-on-bootstrap-carousel)

Comment: You missed the part where I said I wanted to use slick.... but... I'm glad you did...  Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

May be you can have a look here:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-slick-slider-and-image-carousel/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use slider.slick('slickCurrentSlide') to get the current slide position instead of using increment counter. This will also exclude issue when using arrows and manual switching between slides. And also no need too use map for slides.

```
var changeSlide = function(timing) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (timing !== 0) {
      slider.slick('slickNext');
    }
    changeSlide(slider.find('.slick-slide')[slider.slick('slickCurrentSlide')].getAttribute('data-time'));
  }, timing);
}
changeSlide(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the above code https://stackoverflow.com/a/45593522/2931874
The problems that were fixed are **Prev slide** had the wrong time, because the code just set the next slide for the duration.
And **Important** correction was **clearInterval**, all was worked correctly until we change the slide with swipe or arrow. so i removed the prev interval.

```
let intervalId = 0;
    if ($slider.length > 0) {
        $slider.slick({
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            dots: false,
            speed: 1000
        });

        var activeSlides,
            currActiveSlide,
            firstSlide = $slider.find("[data-slick-index='0']");

        $slider.on('beforeChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
            currActiveSlide = slick.$slides.eq(nextSlide);
        });

        $slider.on('afterChange', function (event, slick) {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            intervalId = setTimeout(function () {
                $slider.slick('slickNext');
            }, currActiveSlide.data('time') - 1000);
        });

        // on init
        intervalId = setTimeout(function () {
            $slider.slick('slickNext');
        }, firstSlide.data('time'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried those answers, didn´t work for me.
This does...

What I wanted to achieve was that the first slide should be shown longer then the others. So you can set a default duration for all slides but I want to show a video in the first slide so I need it so stay for 12 seconds which would then be to long/boring for the other slides which should be shown for 7 seconds only.

Also I only needed it to do that for the very first slide as the video then stops and shows a static image. But I guess that example can be expanded to have custom slide-show-times for each slide fairly easy.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var intervalId = 0;
    $slider = $('#homeslider');
    
    var myslider, currentActiveSlide, defaultSpeed = 7000, initSpeed;
    var firstTime = true;
    
    if($('.firstSlide').data('slideshowtime') !== 0 && $('.firstSlide').data('slideshowtime')*1000 != defaultSpeed) {
        initSpeed = $('.firstSlide').data('slideshowtime')*1000;
        firstTime = false;
    } else {
        initSpeed = defaultSpeed;
    }
    
    $slider.on('beforeChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
        currentActiveSlide = slick.$slides.eq(nextSlide);
        
        if(currentActiveSlide.find('.sliderContent').data('slideshowtime') != 0 && firstTime) {
            myslider[0].slick.autoPlayClear;
            myslider[0].slick.options.autoplaySpeed = currentActiveSlide.find('.sliderContent').data('slideshowtime') * 1000;
            myslider[0].slick.autoPlay;
            firstTime = false;
        } else {
            if(myslider[0].slick.options.autoplaySpeed != defaultSpeed) {
                myslider[0].slick.autoPlayClear;
                myslider[0].slick.options.autoplaySpeed = defaultSpeed;
                myslider[0].slick.autoPlay;
            }
        }
    });
    
    myslider = $slider.slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: initSpeed,
        centerMode: false,
        variableWidth: false,
        prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-prev"></button>',
        nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-next"></button>'
    }); 

});

<!-- the html -->

<div id="homeslider">
    <div>
        <div class="firstSlide sliderContent" data-slideshowtime="0"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- more slides -->
</div>
```