# slick slider make delay of start

Tags: javascript, jquery

is it possible to make delay of slider start... I don't want to slider start immediatly, want it to wait 2 sec before start and then slide.

```
$(function() {
    $('.banner').slick({
      autoplay:true,
      autoplaySpeed:2000,
      centerMode: true,
      centerPadding: '50px',
      slidesToShow: 1,
      speed:2000,
      pauseOnFocus: false,
      pauseOnHover: false,
      pauseOnDotsHover: false,
    });
```

Comment: Already answer exit, best example by @Calsal Ans: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38199293/2384642

Comment: Possible duplicate of [slick carousel individual slide duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35489719/slick-carousel-individual-slide-duration)

Comment: Did you try using setTimeout?

Comment: you need to show me to how... @ThanveerShah

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want this at initial page load then simply use a `setTimeout()`  function like this,

```
var count = 0;
    setTimeout(()=>{
        count = 1;
        $('.banner').slick({
          autoplay:true,
          autoplaySpeed:2000,
          centerMode: true,
          centerPadding: '50px',
          slidesToShow: 1,
          speed:2000,
          pauseOnFocus: false,
          pauseOnHover: false,
          pauseOnDotsHover: false,

    },2000) // Initialize the amount of time to delay , Its 2seconds currently.

if(count == 1){
 $(function() {
        $('.banner').slick({
          autoplay:true,
          autoplaySpeed:2000,
          centerMode: true,
          centerPadding: '50px',
          slidesToShow: 1,
          speed:2000,
          pauseOnFocus: false,
          pauseOnHover: false,
          pauseOnDotsHover: false,
        });
      }
```

Comment: Sorry i did not get you

Comment: it is basically checking if count = 0, if 0 then call slider after 2seconds  just once, after calling the function then count will be  1 , If count = 1 then keep the slider running .

Comment: one more thing, on the delay time it's showing all slider images.. is it possible to make it display till delay over?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bit of a cleaner solution than above. Making use of the inbuilt play/pause methods in Slick. Taken from [here](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/776#issuecomment-159219141).

```
var slider = $('.slider');

slider.slick({
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 1000
}).slick("slickPause");

var initialDelay = 3000;

setTimeout(function() {
    slider.slick("slickPlay");
},initialDelay);
```

Answer (score -1):

just control your speed through `speed:2000,` or  `autoplaySpeed:2000,` this will delay your slider according to the given time

Comment: I have two slider, I want to them on same auto play, but want one of them start late to slide. that's why changing autoplay won't solve the probem

Comment: It asked for a start delay, probably due to a pre-loader or something similar! This one will only speed down slide time