# Need slick slider to pause at video start, and play at end of video end, but currently infinitely loops video once it reachs video slide

Tags: javascript, slick.js, autoplay

Let me preface by saying I am no code expert and am novice at best, but have been tasked with trying to fix the JS that is controlling this Slick Slider. Currently the slider will start and play through image slides, but as soon as a video slide comes up, it will infinitely play the video. The goal is to have the slider play infinitely through the entire slideshow, with images and videos, but I want the slider to pause when a video slide is up, have the video play through its entirety, and have the slider continue to the next slide when the video ends. It is also important that when that same video comes up again, it plays from the beginning.

My coworker is also working on this with me and told me to attach this email: We have been working [Code in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zalnv.png) to make the videos play all the way through and I have found a way to make the autoplay pause when there is a slide containing a video (marked in red). I am struggling to find a way to make the autoplay resume when the video is over. At the moment the video just replays endlessly and the slide never changes.  I feel like I’m on the right track (marked in green) but I’m struggling to make it work. I am trying to create an event handler that detects when the current video has ended.

Have tried looking through multiple stack overflows and adding different .js scripts I have found to see if that will fix the problem. The code may be extremely hard for some to look at and I apologize in advance, currently the .JS I have is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.randomize = function (selector) {
        var $elems = selector ? $(this).find(selector) : $(this).children(),
            $parents = $elems.parent();

        $parents.each(function () {
            $(this).children(selector).sort(function (childA, childB) {
                // * Prevent last slide from being reordered
                if($(childB).index() !== $(this).children(selector).length - 1) {
                    return Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5;
                }
            }.bind(this)).detach().appendTo(this);
        });

        return this;
    };
    
    var autoplaytime = 3000;
    $(".slider-scroll").randomize().slick({
    slidesToScroll: 1,
        initialSlide: 0,
      pauseOnFocus: false, 
      pauseOnHover: false,
      dots:false,
     arrows:false,
     autoplay:true,
     autoplaySpeed:autoplaytime,
    });
    

  const slider = $(".slider-scroll");
  var scrollCount = null;
  var scroll= null;
  
  slider.on('wheel', (function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    clearTimeout(scroll);
    scroll = setTimeout(function(){scrollCount=0;}, 200);
    if(scrollCount) return 0;
    scrollCount=1;

    if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
      $(this).slick('slickNext');
    } else {
      $(this).slick('slickPrev');
    }

  }));
   
    
    
});


$(window).on("load",function() {
    if( $('.slick-track').is(':empty') ) {
        $('.notEvent').addClass('show');
    }
});

$(".slider-scroll .slick-current video").on('ended',function(){           
    $('.slider-scroll').slick('slickPlay');
});

// On slide change, pause all videos
$('.slider-scroll').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  $('video').each(function() {
    $(this).get(0).pause();
  });
});


// On slide chnage, play a video inside the current slide
$('.slider-scroll').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  if( $('.slick-slide.slick-current').find('video').length !== 0) 
    {
        $(".slider-scroll .slick-current video")[0].play();
        $('.slider-scroll').slick('slickPause');
    }
});
```

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML as well? Also, be sure to read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This is just so you can get a better idea on how to help us help you in resolving the problem you're facing.

Comment: So the website is built in wordpress, it is meant to take names, dates, birthdays and anniversary's and display them based on set parameters set by the client. I'm not sure there is an HTML file that I can send you that would help. Looking inside the SFTP > VAR > WWW file I cannot see any .HTML files to even send. Initially, the .JS code was almost a direct copy of the code found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35489719/slick-carousel-individual-slide-duration. If there are any PHP files that could help I have a ton of those. Sorry about the Minimal Reproducible Example falling short