# Slick slider - smooth scroll with different slide widths

Tags: javascript, html, slider, slick.js

I'd like to build a smooth scroll slider (Slick slider) when I have different slide widths (variableWidth: true).

Is there a way that my 2nd slider will have the same speed all time (as the first slider with equal slide widths).

```js
$('.gallery').slick({
  arrows: false,
  variableWidth: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 0,
  speed: 3000,
  pauseOnHover: false,
  cssEase: 'linear',
  infinite: true
});
```

```css
.gallery {
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/00ff00/FFF">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/0000ff/FFF">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/ff0000/FFF">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/00ff00/FFF">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/0000ff/FFF">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/ff0000/FFF">
</div>
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/00ff00/FFF">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/0000ff/FFF">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/600x100/00ff00/FFF">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/1600x100/0000ff/FFF">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/50x100/ff0000/FFF">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/600x100/00ff00/FFF">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/1600x100/0000ff/FFF">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/50x100/ff0000/FFF">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking how to make each slide have its own speed. Later we will calculate the correct time for each slide - obviously proportional to the width of the slide.

In order to dynamically set speed, use `slider2.slick('slickSetOption', 'speed', duration)`.

To have more control I use timeout and manually call `slickNext`. The idea is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38199293/3807365). However possibly a better idea is to use events.

```js
// waiting for load so that images fully loaded
window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
  var SPEED = 2000
  var WIDTH = 100
  var imageList = [...document.querySelectorAll('.gallery2 .slide')]

  var slider = $('.gallery').slick({
    arrows: false,
    variableWidth: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 0,
    speed: SPEED,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    infinite: true
  });

  var slider2 = $('.gallery2').slick({
    arrows: false,
    variableWidth: true,
    autoplay: false, // false
    autoplaySpeed: 0,
    speed: SPEED,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    infinite: true
  });

  var widthList = imageList.map(function(item) {
    return item.width
  });



  var slideIndex = 0;
  var changeSlide = function() {
    var duration = SPEED / WIDTH * widthList[slideIndex++]
    slider2.slick('slickSetOption', 'speed', duration)
    slider2.slick('slickNext');
    if (slideIndex >= widthList.length) {
      slideIndex = 0;
    }
    setTimeout(changeSlide, duration);
  }

  changeSlide();


})
```

```css
.gallery {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/00ff00/FFF">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/0000ff/FFF">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/ff0000/FFF">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/00ff00/FFF">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/0000ff/FFF">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/ff0000/FFF">
</div>
<div class="gallery2">
  <img class="slide" src="https://placehold.co/100x100">
  <img class="slide" src="https://placehold.co/100x100/00ff00/FFF">
  <img class="slide" src="https://placehold.co/100x100/0000ff/FFF">
  <img class="slide" src="https://placehold.co/600x100/00ff00/FFF">
  <img class="slide" src="https://placehold.co/1600x100/0000ff/FFF">
  <img class="slide" src="https://placehold.co/50x100/ff0000/FFF">
  <img class="slide" src="https://placehold.co/100x100">
  <img class="slide" src="https://placehold.co/600x100/00ff00/FFF">
  <img class="slide" src="https://placehold.co/1600x100/0000ff/FFF">
  <img class="slide" src="https://placehold.co/50x100/ff0000/FFF">
</div>
```

Comment: That is great! I have a question what does it mean variable WIDTH = 100? Also how I can add the effect 'pauseOnHover': true?

Comment: please note that the original `pauseOnHover` doesn't pause in the middle of a transition, and you got some wide images so that is something to consider before. as for the constants, they are used to calculate the "speed" to be like the first slider, 3000ms for 100px