# How to make this carousel change the image every 'defined' seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I want the output to change the image every 3 seconds. I don't know how to modify the existing output. I can't find the appropriate attribute to edit.

The link to the website is https://www.vimaldevelopers.com. Please help me in inspecting and solving this problem

The link to the image of the carousel https://i.imgur.com/98SsWA0.png (need 10 reputation to post the image so I have to share the link instead)

```css
carousel-item:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.carousel-inner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="container-fluid px-0">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center sliderpaddingtop py-5">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <!-- <div id="headingGroup" class="text-center col-10 col-lg-8  d-lg-block mt-5 pt-md-5"> -->
          <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ul class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="imgs/vc.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="imgs/vh.jpg" alt="Chicago">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="imgs/vi.jpg" alt="New York">
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
            </a>
          </div>
        <!-- </div> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Found the answer on
  https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_ref_js_carousel.asp
- It was dumb of me to not check the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

[You can use this I think](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147394/how-to-change-the-interval-time-on-bootstrap-carousel)

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 1000 * 10
});
```

or

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="1000" data-ride="carousel">
```

Comment: Hi! Tried it but it did not take effect. However, I found the solution in the official documentation of bootstrap. I'll post it here now. Thank you for taking the time to answer. Appreciate it.