# How can I change the interval of my carousel?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, carousel, bootstrap-carousel

I tried changing the interval of my Bootstrap 4 carousel with the following jQuery but didn't got any output. Please let me know what I am missing.

[image]

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 100
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147394/how-to-change-the-interval-time-on-bootstrap-carousel

Comment: As noted in the link above, it *appears* that what you are doing is correct.  Please edit your question to add a complete snippet (can be daunting on the first try).  It needs to include enough HTML (not an image) and links to jquery and the carousel plugin to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: *didn't got any output* - so when you add the interval, it stops working completely?  Does it work without the `{ interval:100 }`?  Does it work without the `.carousel` js line (ie run from data- attributes)?  Is there no output because you've added `d-none` class?

Comment: Please do not share pictures of code. Instead, copy and paste it here.